# Remove duplicated values in JSON using loop

Tags: javascript, json

Take look at:

https://jsfiddle.net/3fmp43db/

```
data = [{
  city: 'Mushroom Kingdom',
}, {
  city: 'Mushroom Kingdom',
}, {
  city: 'Mushroom Kingdom',
}, {
  city: 'Mushroom Kingdom',
}, {
  city: 'Mushroom Kingdom',
}, {
  city: 'Mushroom Kingdom',
}, {
  city: 'Planet Zebes',
}, {
  city: 'Planet Zebes',
}, {
  city: 'Planet Zebes',
}];


for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];

   $(".test").append(obj.city + "<br>")
}
```

It's simple problem, I couldn't figure out how to remove duplicated values before to render this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change last for loop from

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];

   $(".test").append(obj.city + "<br>")
}
```

to

```
var allCities = {};
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    allCities[ data[i].city ] = "";
}
$(".test").append(Object.keys( allCities ).join("<br>"));
```

check this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fmp43db/1/)